# How to add pytorch to a docker file containing a project written in C++?

Tags: python, docker, pytorch

I am working on a project which has a docker image (I am very new to docker). The project is written in C++ but has some python features. I can easily install python when I start the image by doing `apk add python3`, for example. However, this does not work for pytorch. How do I add pytorch to the working environment encapsulated in the docker image? Do I necessarily need to modify the docker image or I can install pytorch after the image has started (just like I do with Python)?

Comment: All the dependencies are way better to install in the image, not in runtime.

Comment: But would there be a way to install pytorch in real time?

Comment: Yes, e.g. using `pip`, which you will also need to install using `apk` (the package name would be `py3-pip`, iirc). I can't think of a reason why anyone would do that though.

Comment: Ok, I will try that thanks. The reason is that it is a large project and that at the moment it would take me more time do modify the dockerfiles architecture.

Comment: Your question boils down to "how do I install pytorch on <OS>". It's irrelevant that you're running in Docker. In any case, go through a Docker tutorial!

Comment: Well, not really. I of course haven't experienced any problems installing pytorch on my machine or others. Somehow it still fails on alpine even after having installed pip3. In any case, yes, I need a docker tutorial - since, at the moment, once pytorch is installed, I may care not too much about the docker file, I went straight to the point

Comment: So, anyone can correct me if I am wrong, but it seems indeed that installing pytorch during run time on docker generates problem because pytorch supports linux distributions which have glibc >= v2.17. But it seems that the glibc version that docker/alpine uses is (at least for me) 1.1.24.